# Is praying for non-Muslims permissible in Islam?

Tags: non-muslim, dua

Can a Muslim pray for a non Muslim?

As far as I know when a Muslim sneezes if someone tells him "Yarhamkom Allah" he can reply by saying "Yahdekom Allah wa yosleh balakom" to him.

Are some prayers not allowed for non Muslims? Can I pray that God guides him to Islam, but can't ask God to forgive him?

What about normal prayers like wishing him to pass an exam or wishing him good health?

Comment: By 'prayer', you didn't mean salah did you? Or 'Du'a' is more appropriate term.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One it is allowed and is very sensible and needed to pray for a non-Muslim to be guided.  But there

> > مَا كَانَ لِلنَّبِيِّ وَالَّذِينَ آمَنُوا أَن يَسْتَغْفِرُوا لِلْمُشْرِكِينَ وَلَوْ كَانُوا أُولِي قُرْبَىٰ مِن بَعْدِ مَا
> >     تَبَيَّنَ لَهُمْ أَنَّهُمْ أَصْحَابُ الْجَحِيمِ
>
> It is not for the Prophet and those who have believed to ask
>   forgiveness for the polytheists, even if they were relatives, after it
>   has become clear to them that they are companions of Hellfire.
>
> (Tawbah: 113)

http://www.ummah.com/forum/showthread.php?297578-To-what-extent-are-we-allowed-to-pray-for-non-Muslims

http://seekersguidance.org/ans-blog/2011/05/23/can-we-pray-for-non-muslims-who-passed-away/

Answer (score 3):

for guidance it is good and no problem and even needed. all prophets came for this.

but for asking forgiveness non-Muslims are two group:
some are believers (for example Christians) who do not have envy and enemty with Islam and for any reason could not know true Islam and if knew Islam without propaganda accepted it. for them there is no problem.

but for those who have envy and enmity with Islam it is prohibited.

ref:

1-

مَا كَانَ لِلنَّبِيِّ وَالَّذِينَ آمَنُوا أَن يَسْتَغْفِرُوا لِلْمُشْرِكِينَ وَلَوْ كَانُوا أُولِي قُرْبَىٰ مِن بَعْدِ مَا تَبَيَّنَ لَهُمْ أَنَّهُمْ أَصْحَابُ الْجَحِيمِ

[[9:113]](http://tanzil.net/#9:113) Sahih International
It is not for the Prophet and those who have believed to ask forgiveness for the polytheists, even if they were relatives, after it has become clear to them that they are companions of Hellfire.

2-

لَّا يَنْهَاكُمُ اللَّـهُ عَنِ الَّذِينَ لَمْ يُقَاتِلُوكُمْ فِي الدِّينِ وَلَمْ يُخْرِجُوكُم مِّن دِيَارِكُمْ أَن تَبَرُّوهُمْ وَتُقْسِطُوا إِلَيْهِمْ ۚ إِنَّ اللَّـهَ يُحِبُّ الْمُقْسِطِينَ

[[60:8]](http://tanzil.net/#60:8) Sahih International
Allah does not forbid you from those who do not fight you because of religion and do not expel you from your homes - from being righteous toward them and acting justly toward them. Indeed, Allah loves those who act justly.

3- http://www.hawzah.net/FA/questionview.html?QuestionID=11663

also we do not know how to pray God correct.
best prayers are passed to us from prophet and Ahl Bayt and it is better we use them and do not use prayers made by ourselves because prayers have many spiritual secrets and effects that we do not know.

best prayers ever:

http://www.al-islam.org/sahifa/

http://duas.org/

Answer (score 1):

- It is forbidden to make dua of forgiveness or mercy for them. This is established though the texts of the Quran such as [9:113](http://quran.com/9/113).
- It is permissible to make dua for them to be guided. There are several examples of this from the Prophet ﷺ, e.g. for the tribe of [Daus](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/80/92), [Thaqif](https://sunnah.com/urn/638360), [Jews](https://sunnah.com/adab/44/14), the [mother of Abu Hurairah](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2491) etc.
- It is also permissible to make dua against them. See [Am I allowed to make Dua against someone?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12358/)
- With respect to dua for their benefit in worldly affairs. Some have considered it permissible when the non-muslim is Dhimmi. They have cited e.g.

  > استسقى النبي صلى الله عليه فسقاه يهودي، فقال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم: جملك . فما رأى الشيب حتى مات
  >
  > The Prophet ﷺ asked for water and a Jew presented it to him. The Prophet ﷺ said: May Allah keep you good-looking. His hair did not become white until his death.
  >
  > <sup>— [عمل اليوم والليلة لابن السني](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13132/548#p1)</sup>

  And also the report about when the [Sahaba did Ruqya](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5736) for a person who is presumed to be a disbeliever. And Ruqya is a type of Dua for the purpose of healing.

  Some others have disagreed as the evidence for the above stance is indirect or weak; and the act is asking for strengthening of the disbelievers.

Answer (score -1):

> It is not for the Prophet and those who have believed to ask forgiveness for the polytheists, even if they were relatives, after it has become clear to them that they are companions of Hellfire. (9:113)

It says not to seek forgiveness.  Does NOT say MERCY.  I was taught by Shaikh aziz that to ask forgiveness of non muslim we cannot but we can ask for his mercy.  Although we know allah swt is merciful.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works. This answer could benefit from provided external sources and [evidence](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3337/how-do-i-add-evidence-to-my-answer) to support your answer.

Comment: @AlexStrasser evidence was provided