# Is it haram and sinful to be greedy in other's dua and asking Allah not to grant them?

Tags: quran, salat, halal-haram, hadith, dua

I am not going to lie, when I was young and ignorant I would make dua to Allah asking him not to grant the duas of the Muslims I hate. They were not good Muslims because they bullied me and so I asked Allah not to grant their wishes. I think I was wrong to do so.

My main question is that in the afterlife when Allah will finally show himself and speak to us. (I know he can speak but he won't after testing us.) If a person gets rewarded lets say with a palace, and a jealous hater will ask or argue with Allah that he/she doesnt deserve it. Like kids, if one gets candy the other kids say mean stuff behind its back. That is what I am afraid that it will happen to me. This boy who hates me said behind my back. "I am going to make dua so she will stop desiring to have what she wants so when she gets to Jannah she wont get i because she doesnt want it,anymore." Is what that boy said sinful and haram?
Plus, once I was asked what I wishes for on Eid and when I told them in the afterlife, they laughed at me saying it was nonsense and ridcilous. I thought Allah could do anything.
 Is laughing or discouraging others from dua haram

Comment: Please take your time with questions to optimise readability and the points you are trying to make, There are a few good points in your question but they can be made clearer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Am I allowed to make Duaa against someone ?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12358/am-i-allowed-to-make-duaa-against-someone)

Comment: Oh, no. My question is different.

Answer (score 1):

"Haram" is a very powerful word and since I am not a scholar I am not going to say that something is that unless there is clear evidence or I am citing the opinion of scholars. But as for making dua to Allah not to grant the dua of others because they are bad people, I think in general it should be avoided.

We have to remember that Allah (swt) is the All Knowing and the All Aware, and as He says in 25:58 "He is Enough to know the sins of His slaves", meaning Allah knows all the wrong that people do and He is enough to punish them for their sins as He sees fits. So we don't need to tell Him how to punish those who wrong us (He is the Judge, not us).

If we are in the situation of being bullied or oppressed, we should instead be glad that we are among the oppressed in that there is no barrier between our dua and Allah. So we should use that opportunity to ask Allah to forgive our sins and to grant good in this life and the next to us and our loved ones. And as for those who wrong us we should just tell Allah that they are His to do with as He pleases for He is the Most Just (and the Most Merciful).

Similarly in the after life if a person really was deserving of Allah's Mercy and Love then no hater can take that away and if a person really was deserving of punishment (because of their oppressing others or whatever sin they did) then Allah Knows best how to punish them (or forgive them if He pleases for that is His right as well as the Lord of us all).

Allah Knows best.

Answer (score 0):

Its not my fault if I born a christian but I am proud to listen about words of God. 
In a Bible it is written love one another and share your blessings to your brothers and sisters… So its truly haram if you become greedy because Allah didnt say feed your own and let others die. 
If you will not be greedy, God will be happy and you will feel light, when every time you think good to your brotherhoid and sisterhood you will be bless.