# Oppression/Bullying

Tags: sharia, dua, non-muslim, non-muslim-countries, depression

I go to school and this girl she always bullies me.(non muslim country)
And she hits me.
I went to the principal about her but nothing was done because there is no proof and this makes me feel very agonized and sad because she always bullies me and never gets punished.I belive in Allah(swt) and I know her day will be here soon when Allah(swt) will make her feel the wrath of the actions she does.I have tried swearing back at her when she does but I decided to stop because I need victory from Allah(swt).
(She is a non muslim)
So please is there any dua, I can make so that she feels what I felt?

Comment: A dua can be made in words of your own choosing. See [Am I allowed to make Dua against someone?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12358/)

Comment: have a search at https://duas.org/

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is dua for that but if there's anything i've learned is that the one who believes and trusts in Allah does not need revenge because Allah will take care of it on his own. I hope that helps you!