# Can I pray for the Israeli Army?

Tags: war, bani-israel, murder

Now that war is going on in the middle east, whole over the world people across religion, caste and creed are praying for the children killed in the war. But no one seems to pray for the killers, that is Israeli Army. We know the fate of children killed in war, they are guarenteed to be in Paradise as they never did any sin. But what about those who are doing the killings, that is the Israeli Army. I feel pity for them as I think their fate is Hell, if they do not repent. So can I pray for the Israeli Army, So that they are guided to truth, at least to what is mentioned in Old testament ?

My question is specific to Israeli Army, so the other questions do not answer my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is praying for non-Muslims permissible in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/503/is-praying-for-non-muslims-permissible-in-islam)

Comment: My question is specific to Israeli Army, so the other questions do not answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends for type of your Dua. if you pray for their guidance and to get guided to the Straight Path there is no problem. but according this verse:

[image]

> You will surely find the most bitter towards the believers to be the
> Jews and polytheists and the most gracious to be those who call
> themselves Christian. That is because there are priests and monks
> among them and because they are not arrogant.

Jews are  the most bitter enemies of believers. so if your pray for their victory against Muslims this is against Quran:

[image]
[image]

> Give good news of a painful punishment to hypocrites,
>
> who choose disbelievers as allies instead of the believers. Do they
> seek honour and power through that company? Surely all honour and
> power belongs to Allah.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It can be useful for people of other religions who are reading this. Jazak Allahu Khayran