# Boycott America?

Tags: halal-haram

If we buy products of USA, they earn money. The more they earn money, the more they pay tax. And as far as I know, a portion of tax from USA is going to Israel, which might be used to kill innocent people of Palestine. So should we boycott American products as well, according to Islam?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe move out of America for those reasons and as well that living in the country of the disbelievers is haram:

Sunan Abi Dawud 2645
Narrated Jarir ibn Abdullah:
The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) sent an expedition to Khath'am. Some people sought protection by having recourse to prostration, and were hastily killed. When the Prophet (ﷺ) heard that, he ordered half the blood-wit to be paid for them, saying: I am not responsible for any Muslim who stays among polytheists. They asked: Why, Messenger of Allah? He said: Their fires should not be visible to one another.

Comment: **WRONG** 

And if living in a country of disbelievers was haram, there wouldn't be many religious Muslims in US. However, it is best for usual Muslims to live in Muslim countries. And I am not living in US too.
And Prophet (peace be upon him) was maybe talking about the Muslims who lived among the polytheists who were enemy of Muslims.

You can delete your answer, as it might mislead people.

Comment: It's haram, if you want to disobey the Messenger that's your problem, the disbelievers, be it Jews Christians or atheists are still our enemies and we should hate the as the the Prophet Ibrahim did in surah 60 verse 4

Comment: Also, there were religious Muslims living amongst the polytheists of Makkah so that contradicts your first point, You being allowed or forbade from living amongst a certain people doesn't correlate to the amount of religious Muslims.

Comment: You're wrong. You can ask a scholar why I said that. Make sure to explain the context too.

Comment: How am I wrong? I showed clear proof from the Quran and Sunnah and you can't debunk that so you just say "aSk a sChOLar".

Answer (score -3):

Why are you concerned of them killing innocents ? When innocents are killed they are directly going to jannah (paradise). We should be more concerned about those who kill innocents because if they don't seek forgiveness they are going to hell for ever. So we should try to indulge more with bad people and try to convey the message of Islam (peace) to them.

> And not equal are the good deed and the bad. Repel [evil] by that
> [deed] which is better; and thereupon, the one whom between you and
> him is enmity [will become] as though he was a devoted friend. [Quran
> 41:34](https://quran.com/fussilat/34)

Our patience should not be our weakness. If they kill and torture us, we should definitely fight them. But we are not worried about the deaths we have in our side, that is my point. And we should not do something that is not at all related like boycotting products of different country, where there are lot of Muslims and good people of other religions live.

Related question : [Can I pray for the Israeli Army?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/80603/can-i-pray-for-the-israeli-army)

Comment: so why prophet a.s. had so many wars with cruel people? why he did not only ask forgiveness instead?

Comment: I have updated my answer, I am not saying we should not fight. But I am against foolish decision like boycotting one countries products.

Comment: this makes no sense to me, this doens't answer the question